# returning code of function instead of result

Tags: jquery

I saved a function created in jQuery in clean.js file..

```
jQuery.fn.singleDotHyphen = function(){
return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val(function(){
        return $this.val()
            .replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')
            .replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');    
    });
});
};
```

My action file is..

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {
$.noConflict();
   $('#title').limitkeypress ({ rexp:/^[A-Za-z.\-\s`]*$/ }); 
       $('#title').blur(function() {
           $(this).singleDotHyphen();  
        });
 }); 
 </script>
```

Issue is onblur its returning me code of the function where as I want to return the  string that reject continuous hyphen and dots...

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery version 1.3.2

Comment: As a side note, `noConflict()` isn't meant to be used inside of a docuemnt ready ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))... it could really mess things up if you happen to have two libraries on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the `.val()` method that accepts a function argument exists only in jQuery 1.4 and above. However, in this case you don't need that version, since you can simply pass the new value to `val()`:

```
$this.val($this.val().replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')
                     .replace(/-{2,}/g, '-'));
```